# Is there any difference between inner join and table separated with a comma?

Tags: mysql

Is there any performance difference between these two query. Both query returns the same result.

```
select * from tbl_a, tbl_b
```

and

```
select * from tbl_a INNER JOIN tbl_b
```

Comment: thank you it helped

Answer (score 1):

There is a thread already touching on this topic. Check it out:

[What is the difference between inner join and outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Performance wise, it will all come down to the amount of data you're working with. A couple tables with a few hundred rows won't make a dent, but you will notice a difference as the amount of data sorted grows.

Good luck!